# Find approppriate ranges for integrals

Tags: integration, statistics

Let $(X,Y)$ have the joint PDF:

$$
f(x,y) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    8xy & : 0 < x < y < 1 \\
    0 & : \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}
\right.
$$

I have trouble finding the ranges for integrals. Is it $0 < x < y$ and $x < y < 1$? I feel it is wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Assuming you want to integrate, you'll have a double integral in which the inner integral will have $x$ as the lower bound. We can check that the integral of the PDF over the entire range is $1$, as it should be:

$$\int_0^1\int_x^1 8xy \,\, \mathrm{d} y \,\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 4x-4x^3 \,\,\mathrm{d}x = 2(1)^2-(1)^4 = 1$$